# Parameter extension for (non-parameter) variables?

Tags: batch-file, parameter-expansion

I have used a `FOR` loop as a **workaround** in a batch script to pare a filename stored in a variable down to just its path:

```
FOR %%f IN ("%f%") DO (SET "o=%tmpdir%\%%~nxf" & SET "d=%%~dpf")
lib\JREPL.BAT "(SourcePath=\q)\.(\q)" "$1%d:$=$$%$2" /XSEQ /f "%f%" /o "%o%"
```

It *seems as if* the [Parameter Extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html#:%7E:text=Parameter%20Extensions) *only* work when you (ab)use the `FOR` operator in this way. The following doesn't work:

```
REM "The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid"
ECHO lib\JREPL.BAT "(SourcePath=\q)\.(\q)" "$1%~dpf:$=$$%$2" /XSEQ /f "%f%" /o "%tmpdir%\%~nxf%"
```

Is this a *true* limitation of CMD (vs. *e.g.* PowerShell or a Unix shell), or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Call it a limitation if you like, but as a `for` variable is not an environment variable, there's no reason to expect them to work in exactly the same way. For example, nobody expects, `%~nxSystemRoot%` or `%~nSystemRoot%` to expand to `Windows` either.

Comment: Were this Unix, I _could_ run, for instance, `_jrepl 'SourcePath=(\q)\.(\q)' '$1'"${f%/*}"'$2' /XSEQ /f "${f}" /o "${tmpdir}/${f##*/}"`. When I say "limitation", I ask whether local vars are, in Batch scripts, limited _relative to_ parameters and for-loops. Coming from Unix, such limitations on vars-vs-params (if they exist (which is what I am asking)) seems a bit strange. And am I using the correct workaround, anyway?

Comment: Well it's a bit strange, because they do exist. Essentially, batch files are a simple mechanism for running a batch of individual commands, it was never designed to be a scripting language.

Comment: It's bad practice to name environment variables with a single letter, because they can easily be confused with `for` meta-variables, which are something completely different; `~`-modifiers are only supported by the latter, and by argument references (like `%1` in a batch file). To me it appears like you are comparing cars with planes, and claiming it's a limitation that cars cannot fly…

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, I've spent my entire life in a world where shell and environment variables are _exactly_ as capable as parameters, so "comparing cars with planes" is a strange analogy. [One can hardly describe Unix as a "flying-car future"...](https://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf)